# Install grub in another machine

Tags: boot, grub2

My hard disk is `/dev/sdb` in machine B. Later it should be used as `/dev/sda` in machine A. It contains the root partition `/` and boot directory `/boot` for machine A.

Is it possible to install grub in advance in machine B?

Answer (score 1):

Just install grub to /dev/sdb

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
```

grub, by default, uses uuid, so it should work.

If you have problems for any reason, you would need to reinstall grub after the transfer.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: Ah, it uses uuid. So it Wouldn't try to boot from the second hard drive (hd1,1) then? Don't I have to specify the mount point of /dev/sdb?